# Successfully Connected to Network but not the Internet

Tags: networking

I'm trying to get one of my desktop computers connected to the internet. I already have a network set up, and I am using a us robotics 5420 network adapter to connect the desktop computer to the network. I am able to successfully connect to the network but I am not able to connect to the internet. I have two other computers running windows 7 which are connected to the same network and internet as well. Thus, I know that there is not a problem with the internet or the router. Here are some of the settings for my network, the security mode is wpa-personal and the encryption type is tkip. I am not sure what is wrong, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: This will sound completely facetious but do you have a modem that's working and connected to the network somehow?

Comment: Yup the modem is working fine. I have the modem wired to the router and have two computers connected wirelessly to the router and these two computers are able to connect to the internet. The problem is with the third computer. Although, I am able to connect to the network, I am not able to connect to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

It could always be something silly like a firewall blocking port 80 on your computer for some unknown reason, this was the case for me a few months ago.

Answer (score 0):

I would just double check that you have typed the correct security code and/or encryption type as I have noticed a few times that if you have one of the settings incorrect, some routers can make it look like you are connected when you actually are not.

Also, just in general, make sure that you actually have a valid IP address and not a link-local/similar address. If you do, it is possible that you need to manually set up the IP address. Pay extra attention to the DNS server and make sure that it is configured.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think that the problem for this desktop computer is that it does not have an IP address. I don't know why this is the case since I was able to connect my other two computers to the internet simply by connecting them to the network.